# How to identify user when using the Basic authentication?

Tags: symfony, authentication, curl, fosrestbundle

I am using the basic auth in the  FOSRestBundle. Cheking my API through CURL commands showed me it is working perfectly.

But now, I am wondering to identify the user who did the POST action ( **Imagine the use wants to post a comment on something! Who is that user?** ). In fact, as you can see in the CURL command below, the user and his password are encoded in base64.

```
# POST
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -H "Content-type: application/json" \
 -H "Authorization: Basic YW1pbmU6c3RpZ21hdGFn" \
 -X POST -d '{"test":{"x":"Amine","y":"Jallouli"}}'
 http://localhost/tuto/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/test/add
```

Any recommendations?

FYI, this is my config in security.yml

```
firewalls:
    #.....
    rest_api:
        pattern: ^/api/
        stateless: true
        http_basic:
            provider: fos_userbundle
```

Comment: you should be able to use the security context to get the user in your controller, `$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to use this @amine

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```